# Prove that a function is injective

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the function $f(x)={{x^3+9}\over{x^2}}$ and I'm trying to prove that it is injective in $(-\infty, 0)$ through the definition.

**What I've done:**

$
f(a)=f(b)\Leftrightarrow
{{a^3+9}\over{a^2}}={{b^3+9}\over{b^2}}\Leftrightarrow
b^2(a^3+9)=a^2(b^3+9)\Leftrightarrow
a^3b^2+9b^2=a^2b^3+9a^2\Leftrightarrow\\
a^3b^2-a^2b^3=9a^2-9b^2\Leftrightarrow
a^2b^2(a-b)=9(a-b)(a+b)\Leftrightarrow
a^2b^2=9(a+b)
$

From this point on, I'm pretty much doing circles without ever reaching $f(a)=f(b)\Leftrightarrow a=b$.

**Question:**

How can I prove that $f(x)$ is an injective function? Any tip that will help me get unstuck from where I am and points to me the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that to prove injectivity, you only need to show that if $a,b  \in (-\infty,0)$ with $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$.

There are two cases to consider:

- If $a=b$, then we are done.
- Otherwise, assume $a \neq b$. Continuing from where you left, we get $$a^2b^2=9(a+b)$$

Since $x^2 \geq 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that $a^2b^2 \geq 0$.

On the other hand, as $a,b<0$, it follows that $9(a+b)<0$

So, we have arrived at a contradiction. Thus, this case is not possible.

This shows that our required function is injective.

Comment: Using the result of the first derivative to determine the monotony of $f$ and, thus, prove its injectivity, as the other answers propose, sounds the easiest thing to do, but I'll give you the checkmark, since your answer solves my actual problem directly instead of using an alternative path.

Answer (score 1):

Write 
$$
f(x)=x+\frac{9}{x^2} 
$$ and observe that
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{18}{x^3}
$$
so that $f$ is increasing since $f'(x)>0$ for $x<0$ and thus injective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$f(x)={{x^3+9}\over{x^2}}=x+\frac{9}{x^2}\implies f'(x)=1-\frac{18}{x^3}>0$$

thus f is strictly increasing and injective in $(-\infty, 0)$ .